# convert svg into html area maps with coords

Tags: jquery, html, maps, photoshop

can anybody help me with problem.
How to convert svg into html area maps with coords. I found some site where i must again drow the point and then hi give me html with coords.
Anybody know easier  way to do thet some sofftvare for convert or how photoshop or Adobe ilustrator can do thet?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you now php? I might have something for you.

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to try your luck and use [the python script by David Lynch](http://davidlynch.org/blog/2008/03/creating-an-image-map-from-svg/). It is said to convert SVG files into image (`area`) maps. You should [install Python 2.x](http://www.python.org/download/) beforehands.